# How to map Bootstrap Modal to Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form in Bootstrap Modal and I want my Spring MVC controller to listen that. My problem is that the modal doesn't generate href because it's inside current page so I can't map just the modal in my Spring MVC controller.

I need it, because I want to show errors from bindingresult object. How can I do this?

This is my modal: http://www.bootply.com/zerZIYpNAF Let's say it's located in index.jsp so imaginary path would be /index#myModal.jsp or something like that.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Dummybean bean){
    return "??"; //index#myModal
}

@RequestMapping(value="/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@Valid @ModelAttribute("dummy") DummyBean bean, BindingResult bindingResult){

if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "??"; //index#myModal
    }
//do something
}



public class DummyBean{


@NotNull
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return username;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call the bootstrap modal to pop up by using controller. There for you will not able to bind form with Spring. But you can Achieve it using Ajax. You have to use form like normal Html form without using spring tags.

```
function searchAjax() {
    var data = {}
    data["query"] = $("#query").val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "${home}search/api/getSearchResult",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display(data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
}
```

This is an example ajax for you to get an idea. You have to `HttpServletRequest` to retrieve data from controller side. Above example is taken from http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/

Answer (score -1):

1) create new function just for validation

2) create js function using prefer to use jquery and send ajax request to function in step one.

3) depend on validation status will handle errors or send form completely.

please read this article it's fully answered your question 
[javacodegeeks.com](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-and-jquery-for-ajax-form.html)